# How can I set a simple multi-line ItemReader and configure bulk operations job to be resumable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to accomplish a simple task of:

1. Read a text file that contains SQL queries separated by ";".
2. Perform each query in a separate transaction
3. Be able to restart/resume the execution from the first query that failed.

I tried to do this with spring-batch.(version 2.1.8.RELEASE)
The problems I am facing are as follows:

I failed to configure a simple out-of-the-box `ItemReader` that would read several lines up to ";" and aggregate them before passing to the `ItemWriter`.

I do not need a `FieldSetMapper` I simply do not have no fields. My input is a text file containing SQL queries. Each query can take 1 or more lines and the queries are separated by a semicolon. Seems like it is impossible to define an `LineMapper` inside a `ItemReader` without specifying a `FieldSetMapper` to a complex bean (I tried to set a `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper` to map to `java.lang.String` but failed due the exception described below).

**Question 1:**  why do I need a `FieldSetMapper` with the `prototypeBeanName` set to a complex object if all I want is to append all the lines in a single `String` before passing it to the `ItemWriter`? When I configure the `fieldSetMapper`'s property `prototypeBeanName` to refer to the `java.lang.String` I get an Exception saying that the number of names is not equal to the number of values. I debugged the spring-batch code and found that there are 2 values mapped to a single name: **name**=%SOME_NAME% **values**={%MY_SQL_QUERY%, ";"}   and the Exception is thrown by `AbstractLineTokenizer.tokenize()` line 123

**Question 2**: Can the line aggregation be achieved by using out-of-the box spring-batch `ItemReaders` if yes, how they need to be configured? Do I miss something in my configuration? (see below)

configuration:

```
<bean id="basicParamsIncrementer" class="com.linking.core.exec.control.BasicJobParamsIncrementer" />

<batch:job id="rwBatchJob" restartable="true" incrementer="basicParamsIncrementer">
    <batch:step id="processBatchStep">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" >
            <batch:chunk reader="batchFileItemReader" writer="sqlBatchFileWriter" 
                   commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>


<bean id="batchFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource"
        value="classpath:/bat.sql.txt" />
    <property name="recordSeparatorPolicy" ref="separatorPolicy" />

    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer" ref="sqlTokenizer" />
            <property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="sqlFieldSetMapper" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="separatorPolicy" class="com.linking.core.SemiColonRecordSeparatorPolicy" />

<bean id="sqlTokenizer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
    <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
    <property name="names" value="sql,eol"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sqlFieldSetMapper" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="sql" />
</bean>


<bean id="sql" class="com.linking.core.model.SQL" scope="prototype" />
```

`com.linking.core.model.SQL` is a simple class having 2 members of type `String`: sql (for the query) and `eol` (for the ';') It is used to overcome the situation that the `AbstractItemReader` returns all the lines up to the separator (as a `String`) and also the separator (in my case ";") as `values`.

**Question 3:** In case the job that runs a bulk of SQL queries using just a single step reader-writer approach fails in the middle how can I resume/restart the job from the 1st failed query? Should I do it programatically by analyzing last run or can it be achieved by context configuration of the job-step and the related out-of-the-box spring-batch beans?

Comment: Look into using a [PassThroughFieldSetMapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/PassThroughFieldSetMapper.html).  It simply returns the fieldSet, allowing you to use it directly in your ItemProcessor/ItemWriters.

Answer (score 0):

For question 3, I would do couple of things

- In item reader you can pass an attribute like "saveState" to true
- Set "commit-interval" to a suitable value
- Configure Spring batch DB, so it can save the state

If all above are set, and you don't use "next" for job instance, it will resume where you left!